Selenium mail.ru авторегистрация
Не могу разобраться с датами на mail.ru. Не находит элемент по XPATH. Данные об аккаунте записываются в отдельный файл на 74 строке. Выдает ошибку:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//option[contains(text(),'8')]"}

Все галочки уже ставит и все работает кроме этих дат.
import random
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
numerals = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
firstmailsuffix = "@mail.ru"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
num = 0
keylogs = open("mails", "a+")
while (True):

    num+=1
    passwordfull = ""
    keys = []
    mailname = 'kazakvolskyoi'
    for i in range(10):

        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            keys.append(random.choice(letters))
        else:
            keys.append(random.choice(numerals))

    driver.get('https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main_m_touch')
    time.sleep(5)


    mail = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="partial_login"]')

    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="password"]')
    password.click()
    repeat = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="repeatPassword"]')

    fname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="fname"]')
    lname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id="lname"]')

    gender = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form/div[9]/div[2]/div/label[1]/div[1]/div[2]')

    sday = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]')
    smonth = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]')
    syear = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]')

    searchbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/form/button')

    fname.click()
    fname.send_keys("Valorant")
    lname.click()
    lname.send_keys("Account")

    gender.click()
    sday.click()
    day = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[contains(text(),'8')]")
    day.click()
    smonth.click()
    month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[contains(text(),'Март')]")
    month.click()
    syear.click()
    year = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[contains(text(),'2000')]")
    year.click()


    mail.click()
    mail.send_keys(str(mailname), str(num))

    password.click()
    for passkey in keys:
        passwordfull += passkey
    password.send_keys(passwordfull)
    repeat.send_keys(passwordfull)
    keylogs.write(f"Mail: {mailname}{num}{firstmailsuffix} // Password: {passwordfull}\n")

    searchbutton.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.close()


Во-первых, никогда не ищи по full XPATH. Со временем он меняется. В будущем программа не будет работать.
Насчет твоей проблемы - вот ее решение:
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-id='select-value:2']").click()

Данная строчка кода выполняет нажатие на 2 число дня рождения.
Остальные метрики найди сам. Проскрабь страницу с помощью driver.page_source в момент нажатия на дату, или год, или день.
Затем посмотри код, и увидишь class='selenium-menu-wrapper'. Там найдешь ответ на остальные вопросы.
